# Docker volume not available during execution

Tags: docker

Maybe this question has been asked before, although I didn't find the answer.

I'm using [cozy-labs/cozy-docker](https://github.com/cozy-labs/cozy-docker) and I'd like to let it save all the data on a mounted volume.

Actually, I tried putting my database folder in `/var/lib/couchdb` (as in `/etc/couchdb/local.ini`, there's no such option therefore this must be the default, right?) and mounting it in docker as follows:

```
docker run -d --name some-name -v /myData/:/var/lib/couchdb -p 4001:443 cozy/full
```

But the folder `/myData` on the host stays empty whereas in the docker, `/var/lib/couchdb` seems to contain the files it should. I verified this entering the container using `docker exec -it some-name bash`

What could I be misunderstanding?

And honestly, I don't think this is specific to [cozy-docker](https://github.com/cozy-labs/cozy-docker)

Comment: Just guessing, but have you tried -v /myData:/var/lib/couchdb, without the '/' behind /myData? The official doc doesn't use it.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sure that on the both sides you have the same inode values.

```
docker run -d --name some-name -v /myData/:/var/lib/couchdb -p 4001:443 cozy/full
stat -c %i /myData
docker exec -it some-name stat -c %i /var/lib/couchdb
```

So what are these values? They should be equal, but if they differ, the content of the dirs will be differing to obviously.

I tested this image on Ubuntu 14.10, Docker 1.5 and I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: The values are equal. But nevertheless, the images doesn't seem to write into this folder.